# Can I adapt my Safe smart contract before deployment and use the Safe {Core} SDK?

Tags: gnosis-safe

My question is if it is possible to change some staff about the smart contract of my Safe, deploy it, and also use its SDKs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

To use a forked version of the Safe contracts with the SDK you would need deploy the contract by yourself. Once deployed, you should use the `contractNetworks` variable to tell the SDK what contracts should be used (your custom one) instead of the official ones when initializing the SDK.

Here there is the API reference where you can find more info about that property in the `create` method: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/protocol-kit#create-1